# Access 2016 create table with field properties for combobox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to work out how to use a create table sub in Access 2016 to add a field that has a control property set to combo box.

Using code I've gleaned from various sources, I've managed to get the following to run, except for the creating a combo box.

The table itself needs to have the combobox set up, as it eventually gets uploaded to SharePoint.

Please help?

```
Sub maketable()
Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim myTable As DAO.TableDef
 Dim myField As DAO.Field

     Set db = CurrentDb

     Set myTable = db.CreateTableDef("TestTable")
         With myTable
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("DateD", dbDate)
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("Description", dbText)
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("Num1", dbDouble)
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("Num2", dbDouble)
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("yesno", dbBoolean)
         .Fields.Append .CreateField("listme", dbText)
     End With

     db.TableDefs.Append myTable

    Set myField = myTable.Fields("DateD")
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "Format", dbText, "Short Date")

    Set myField = myTable.Fields("Num1")
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "DecimalPlaces", dbByte, 2)
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "Format", dbText, "Standard")

     Set myField = myTable.Fields("listme")
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "DisplayControl", dbText, acComboBox)
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "RowSourceType", dbText, acvaluelist)
     Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "RowSource", dbText, "Test1;Test2")

    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

     Set myField = Nothing
     Set myTable = Nothing
     Set db = Nothing

End Sub

Function SetDAOProperty( _
     WhichObject As Object, _
     PropertyName As String, _
     PropertyType As Integer, _
     PropertyValue As Variant _
 ) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim prp As DAO.Property

    WhichObject.Properties(PropertyName) = PropertyValue
     WhichObject.Properties.Refresh
     SetDAOProperty = True

Cleanup:
     Set prp = Nothing
     Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
     Select Case Err.Number
         Case 3270 ' "Property not found"
             Set prp = WhichObject.CreateProperty( _
                 PropertyName, _
                 PropertyType, _
                 PropertyValue _
             )
             WhichObject.Properties.Append prp
             WhichObject.Properties.Refresh
             SetDAOProperty = True
         Case Else
             MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
             SetDAOProperty = False
     End Select
     Resume Cleanup

 End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, just two changes are needed:

1.

```
Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "DisplayControl", dbText, acComboBox)
```

`DisplayControl` is not a text but an integer property:

```
Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "DisplayControl", dbInteger, acComboBox)
```

2.

Here the VBA editor already gives a hint that there is a problem:

```
Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "RowSourceType", dbText, acvaluelist)
```

`acvaluelist` does not exist. `RowSourceType` is a text property, the [correct assignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835376.aspx) is:

```
Call SetDAOProperty(myField, "RowSourceType", dbText, "Value List")
```

Note: The 2nd one would have been picked up by having
[`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time.

To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Comment: Andre, you are my hero, it worked perfectly, thank you!