# Setting the RowSource property of a field which has a ComboBox Display Control in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a dynamic temporary table using VBA. The table stores some values in order to be processed and confirmed by the user before being stored to the database.

I managed to display one of the table's fields as a ComboBox using the code below

```
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", vbLong, acComboBox)
fld.Properties.Append prp
```

However I don't know how to populate the ComboBox displayed field.
I tried creating another property for the RowSourceType and the RowSource but I don't know how to fill the parameters.

```
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSourceType", ?, ?)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access 2016 create table with field properties for combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476808/access-2016-create-table-with-field-properties-for-combobox)

Comment: FWIW, the type value should be set to `dbInteger`, not `vbLong`. They both represent the constant 3, but that's accidental. So: `Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("DisplayControl", dbInteger, AcControlType.acComboBox)`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer shortly after I posted the question.
I'll leave the answer for anyone who might need it.

```
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSourceType", dbText, "Table/Query")
fld.Properties.Append prp
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("RowSource", dbText, "SELECT * FROM TBL;")
fld.Properties.Append prp
```

You can also add the two properties below to set the column count and the column width.

```
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("ColumnCount", dbInteger, 2)
fld.Properties.Append prp
Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("ColumnWidths", dbText, "0;1440")
fld.Properties.Append prp
```